# Kivy - Make a class

Tags: python, kivy

I'm searching how to put same properties of buttons in a group like the css language...

I've got this kivy file :

```
<Clavier>:
    Button:
        pos: 0, root.width / 5
        size: root.width / 10 , root.width / 10
        text: 'A'

    Button:
        y: root.width / 5
        x: root.width / 10
        size: root.width / 10 , root.width / 10
        text: 'Z'

    Button:
        y: root.width / 5
        x: root.width / 5
        size: root.width / 10 , root.width / 10
        text: 'E'

    Button:
        y: root.width / 5
        x: root.width * 3 / 10
        size: root.width / 10 , root.width / 10
        text: 'R'

    Button:
        y: root.width / 5
        x: root.width * 4 / 10
        size: root.width / 10 , root.width / 10
        text: 'T'
...
```

Can we get this code optimized ?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this easily with [dynamic classes](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#dynamic-classes)! Start with the common properties:

```
<MyButton@Button>:
    size: root.width / 10, root.width / 10
```

Then you can finish with the differing properties:

```
MyButton:
    text: 'A'

MyButton:
    text: 'Z'
```

Comment: It doesn't work, can you give more code please ? Thanks.